# Keyboard and mouse don't work on windows login page

Tags: windows, usb, keyboard, bios, login-screen

The situation is that keyboard and mouse DO work perfectly on the same machine on the same ports when you press F2/F12 and go to BIOS/CMOS setup. it works all the way up and down and the mouse clicks and everything. But then when you let it go to the windows login page NEITHER of them works.

The system is windows 10 and it was going through updates recently. Also, the bios error log shows error logs such as "keyboard not found" twice in last two months. I checked all the bios configuration and all USB ports are activated and even power sharing on USB was enabled and disabled and neither case it worked.

When it stays on the long page for long the monitor turns off, and if I plug in and out any of the keyboard or mouse the monitor turns back on. I think this means something.

it's a Dell XPS 8900 device.

Comment: Have you tested with other keyboards and mice such as your friends'.

Comment: @AungMyat the same keyboard and mouse works on the same system when in bios mode. but when it comes to login page it does not work. do you think I should clarify the question on this?

Comment: If I were you in this situation, I would tested with other keyboard and mouse. Can you toggle keyboard lights such as Caps Lock, Num Lock, etc. at the login page?

Comment: @AungMyat when i am in bias mode (Dell XPS 8900) yes, the lights change and keyboard works perfectly. but as soon as I restart it goes to login mode and then the keyboard lights don't toggle at caps lock and etc. I restored the BIOS to default and it did not help either! I de-activated front and top UBS ports assuming it might be a power issue. and deactivated power share as well. none of these helped!

Comment: I highly suspect it might have something to do with updates.

Comment: It could be that the drivers need to be installed as ‘admin’, so they are available in the login screen. If you have an alternative way to log in, do so, and then go to an admin account, and plug the devices in question in.

Comment: @Aganju is there a way to log in without a keyboard? that's where I am stuck at? I am getting more certain this is a window update going wrong and taking forever.